# Check Routing parameters in Angular2

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem in conditional routing where the scenario is

Consider a routing link as `WWW.IP.com/admin/home/1`

Based on this i need a solution for WWW.IP.com/admin/home/*

`*` represents any
Is there any possibilities for my scenario

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are not getting your point,please explain exact problem with code

Comment: my question is to check if it contains the url that starts with admin/home and there by any url it preceeds

Comment: As per my understanding do you want to capture url like `admin/home/1` or `admin/home/Index` in your component ? or you want to access value after `/home/anyvalue`